# The output shows wrong results

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pls help me with this. It counts wrong. I think it would probably be because it counts from 1 but not from 0. How should i edit the code?

My task is: If the Array Element is less than 10
assign zero values, and assign items over 20 to 1

```
a = [1,3,4,5,6,34,51,44,12,42,1,4,2,31,30]
b = []
for i in a:
    if i < 10:
        b.append(0)
    elif i > 20:
        b.append(1)
print(b)
```

My output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

But it gotta be like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: what if `i` is not < 10 and not > 20 as it happens when it's 12? then you are not processing it at all

Comment: Why do you think it should be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are only checking for less than 10 or more than 20, and there is a 12 in your array, which doesn't fit either. There really isn't a way you can edit the code to make it give you the desired output without drastically changing the rules you had before. Are you sure that `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]` is the correct output?

Comment: Got it. Yeah, that output is correct

Comment: @David The only way I can think of then would be to change the `elif` to an `else`, but that would obviously be changing the rules.